# Linq repeat every nth element for a given range within a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of custom objects, eg:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int MyField { get; set; }
}
```

The list has 12 objects, where the MyField property is initially 0, so the objects would be:

> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

I would like to repeat every n times skipping x items. So if I have repeat 2 and skip 3, the new values should be:

> 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

If I want to repeat 3 times and skip 4, the new values would be:

> 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0

Is it possible to do this using `Linq`?

Comment: Can you provide more examples using 0s and 1s instead of true false. Not very clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: It would make sense to use LINQ to create a new list, permuted as you describe, but not to alter the existing one. So you could write a new extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` which would do what you need. Something like `list = list.MyThing(2,3,x => x + 1)`, where `MyThing` calls the lambda to get a new value for the items indicated by the skip/repeat parameters, and returns the other items as it finds them. All the hepcats nowadays are like bro, do you even immutable? OMG that collection is literally so mutable, I like can't even.

Comment: Note that my approach is a fun exercise but probably counterproductive in terms of getting your feature out the door.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  You *can* write linq methods that have side effects, but because of lazy enumeration and other factors, a straight `for` or `foreach` loop is preferred:

```
int repeat = 2;
int skip = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count && repeat > 0; i += skip)
{
    list[i].MyField = 1;
    repeat--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly combine two approaches using a [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.100).aspx) clause to target every nth element via :

```
// This would target every nth element of your collection (i being the index)
collection.Where((x,i) => i % n == 0);
```

Along with a [`Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) call to skip a specific number of elements :

```
// This would skip n elements, returning those that remained after the nth index
collection.Skip(n);
```

It may be simpler to just use a loop and iterate through your individual elements, checking your condition via the modulo operator `%` (to see if it is the nth element) and then using a `Skip()` when necessary.